# Angular 4 formArrayName for drop-down list

Tags: angular

I can pass value in following way

template:

```
<td formArrayName="itemnameS">
<div *ngFor="let itemname of itemnameS.controls; let i=index">
<input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="Item Name">
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
form = new FormGroup({
    itemnameS: new FormArray([
      new FormControl('Gloves'),
      new FormControl('Gauze'),
      new FormControl('Needles'),
    ]),
    quantitieS: new FormArray([
      new FormControl(''),
    ]),
  });
```

Could please let me know how it is possible for drop down list as follows:

```
<select  formArrayName="itemnameS">
<option *ngFor="let itemname of itemnameS.controls; let i=index" >
                {{ ?? }}
</option>
</select>
```

Should look like as bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create formArray :

```
form = new FormGroup({
    itemnameS: new FormArray([null]), // null to have at least one item initially
    quantitieS: new FormArray([
      new FormControl(''),
    ]),
  });

this.myItems = ['Gloves','Gauze','Needles'];
```

and then :

```
<div *ngFor="let control of form.get('itemnameS').controls ; let i = index" >
      <select  formControlName="control">
           <option *ngFor="let itemname of myItems; let i=index [value]='itemname' >
                {{ itemname }}
     </option>
</select>
  <button (click)="addNewOne()">Add</button>

        <button (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Don't forget, a `select` is simply a user input and a user input could only have one controller, so one `formControl` must be assigned to it because eventually it's gonna have one value saved to your database.

and then if you wanted to implement the `add` new item functionality :

```
 addANewOne(){
     this.form.get('itemnameS').push(new FormControl())

  }
```

and for remove

```
 remove(index){
     this.form.get('itemnameS').removeAt(index)

  }
```

Comment: Thanks Milad. You replyed so fast :). Your code is working fine. Just one thing I just forgot to ask. This is nested form. So json should look like ["Gloves","Gauze","Needles"] when submitting the form. Need your help. I just updated the picture above.

Comment: I think I just wrote your whole task hahaha:

Comment: Yes thanks :). But it is throughing error -> Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: what ? You had used it before hahah

Comment: alright, I had forgotten  to put `let` before `control` , that's it

Comment: I have added it but still it is not showing dropdown and there is no error

Comment: Ok. But why template driven form is bad ?

Comment: Hi I have fixed this for my case. Thanks for your help and advice :). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892187/angular-4-nested-dropdown/45895209#45895209