# Angular 4 nested dropdown

Tags: angular

I trying to add a nested drop-down. If we click "Add City", it will create another drop-down. I was successful without drop-down. Please see bellow

[image]

..component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <select  formControlName="cities">
    <option *ngFor="let city of myCities; let i=index" [value]='itemname' >
      {{ city }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <button (click)="addCity()">Add City</button>
  <button (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
 form = new FormGroup({
    cities: new FormControl([null]),
  });


  myCities = ['Dhaka','Dubai','Munich'];


  get cities(): FormArray { return this.form.get('cities') as FormArray; }

  addCity() { this.form.get('cities').push(new FormControl())}

  remove(index){ this.form.get('cities').removeAt(index) }
```

Showing error as bellow:

> E:/angular/nestedForm2/src/app/order-form/order-form.component.ts
>   (21,39): Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
>
> E:/angular/nestedForm2/src/app/order-form/order-form.component.ts
>   (23,42): Property 'removeAt' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

I have tried in different ways but still did not find any solution. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formArrayName="cities">

      <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; let i=index">

        <select [formControlName]="i">

            <option *ngFor="let itemname of myCities" [value]='itemname' >
                {{ itemname }}
            </option>

        </select> 

      </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>

  <br>

  <button (click)="addCity()">Add City</button>
  <button (click)="remove(i)">Remove City</button>
```

component.ts:

```
import { AbstractControl, FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-form',
  templateUrl: './order-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-form.component.css']
})
export class OrderFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form = new FormGroup({
    cities: new FormArray([
      new FormControl([null]),
    ]),
  });



  myCities = ['Dhaka','Dubai','Munich'];


  get cities(): FormArray { return this.form.get('cities') as FormArray; }

    addCity() { this.cities.push(new FormControl()); }

    remove(index) { (this.form.get('cities') as FormArray).removeAt(index) }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.cities.value);  // ['SF', 'NY']
    console.log(this.form.value);    // { cities: ['SF', 'NY'] }
  }

  setPreset() { this.cities.patchValue(['LA', 'MTV']); }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around the errors you have, you need to cast your [`AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) to its subclass [`FormArray`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) where `push` and `removeAt` are defined.

```
(this.form.get('cities') as FormArray).push(new FormControl())
(this.form.get('cities') as FormArray).removeAt(index)
```

You have to do this because TypeScript cannot determine the exact type of `form.get('cities')`, since you're accessing it by providing a string. Only you as a developer know, based on the structure of the data in your form, that `form.get('cities')` will contain a `FormArray`.

Comment: Thank you Lazar. Could you please tell me how can I cast?

Comment: I've provided a code snippet in my answer. You use `as` to cast, as I've shown there.

Comment: I have done this  addCity()  { (this.form.get('cities') as FormArray).push(new FormControl())} & remove(index){ (this.form.get('cities') as FormArray).removeAt(index) }. But still find error "ERROR TypeError: this.form.get(...).push is not a function"

Comment: That's a runtime error and has nothing to do with your question. It means that your logic is bad.

Comment: Is there any way out to make nested drop-down ?

Comment: Hello Lazar, so I have solved this and your comment was very helpful. Thanks :)